# facebook sharing not display required images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am going to implement Facebook sharing in my rails website for user posts, we already have meta OG data in application.I am using the following URL to sharing

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Title+here&p[url]=http://example.com&p[summary]=I+love+cheese&p[images][0]=http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rm.jpg" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

The problem is the Facebook sharer doesn't fetch the image give in link instead of that it fetches from the meta og data image. But I need to post particular image to Facebook stream. I have also used Facebook javascript  sdk but the result is same. How to say sharer not fetch og data and fetch the image we have given?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook disabled custom sharer parameters:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/

I had similiar problem and I have solved it by creating "fake" url which provides different og-tags and redirect as fast as possible to the "real" url.

Comment: will you please explain what to do?

Comment: So, let say you want to share Wikipedia cat page with the image of your own cat:
https://gist.github.com/Maskl/1cffbccc01fac592aab9

Of course it is just to show the idea, it would be better to connect this solution with your application backend.

Comment: And other thing I have to say is I have many post in a same page itself so how to describe og data for each post?

Comment: You should have different URLs for each post with og-tags connected with them and just share that URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't achieve what you're trying to do as of today.

Facebook `og:image` always has the priority over the URL custom parameters, therefore you will have to either 1) change the `og:image` tag in the page to share.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://image" />
```

or 2) remove the `og:image` tag so that your `p[image]` parameter will be taken into consideration.